# java JList wont refresh, works in debugger

Tags: java, jlist

```
JList Jlist;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
DefaultListModel<String> myModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

Jlist = new JList<String>();
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(Jlist);
```

i send the JList and myModel to another class where they do the following.

```
myModel.addElement(aString);
Jlist.setModel(myModel );
```

This updates the JList in the debugger. When i run it live however i don't see the changes in the JList in my GUI but the variables are there in the debugger.

EDIT #1
    made changes as recommended by answer:

```
DefaultListModel<String> myModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList Jlist = new JList<String>(myModel );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(Jlist);
```

in the other class.

```
myModel.addElement(aString);
```

sadly the issue remains

problem was due to concurrency i was not protecting a shared resoure properlly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and most likely should in your case) add elements after you've created the list and initialized it with a model:

```java
jlist = new JList<String>(myModel);
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jlist);
```

Then just pass the model to the class that populates it:

```java
myModel.addElement(aString);
```

Also, there could be such a problem if you'd change the model in a non-UI thread. To check if that's the thing, try invoking the `addElement` inside `invokeLater`:

```java
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myModel.addElement(aString);
    }
});
```

Comment: sadly it did not work, i updated my post with how my code looks now

Comment: @johndenver It's hard to say what's happening without understanding the structure of the second class, but I still think it's a concurrency issue. I've edited my answer.

Comment: ok great, that actually did it, so concurrency is the problem. So does mean i need to synchronise everytime i do .addElement, with a blocking queue or similar?

Comment: That depends on where this happens (e.g., the action handlers are already executed on the UI thread). This is a tricky topic, so I'd recommend reading a good book on it, like "Core Java" by Kay Horstmann or Java Tutorials part on Swing Concurrency https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html